# data conversion error in SSIS 2005

Tags: sql-server

I am encountering a tough problem when doing data conversion. My work is to generate fact table in ssis 2005, and there are several data that should be converted to other data type, so I use data conversion to change the data type to expected. My work flow is: 
**raw data-->dim lookup-->data conversion-->destination OLEDB**

All process goes well while stopped in data conversion, and the error is " *The conversion returned status value 2 and status text  "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.*".

Some said the reason maybe there are NULLs in raw data, so I've changed the NULLs to UNEXPECTED, so no NULLs in raw data, but the same error also exists.

Comment: What are the data types from the conversion?